# How often does EventHubClient open AMQP connections?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Does `EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString` method open an AMQP connection and reuse it every time an event is sent or a new connection is opened every time SendAsync method is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide#event-publishers), it will reuse the AMQP connection:

AMQP 1.0 connections are metered as brokered connections in Service Bus and are more appropriate in scenarios with frequent higher message volumes and lower latency requirements, **as they provide a persistent messaging channel**.